# Does JMeter Support response size of 22 MB?

Tags: jmeter

There is an API call in Http Request sampler which returns 22 MB size of Response data.

When I execute JMeter test, It returns below info in view status tree.
Response too large to be displayed. Size:23474761.

Is this just an information message or the response itself is not handled/supported by JMeter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does, the limitation is intentional.

It's controllable by [`view.results.tree.max_size` JMeter property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous)

> Maximum size (in bytes) of HTML page that can be displayed.
> Set to zero to disable the size check and display the whole response.
> Defaults to: 10485760

So if you want to see the response body fully you need to add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
view.results.tree.max_size=0
```

and the limitation will go away after JMeter restart.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

However it might be a better idea to store response data into a separate file using i.e. [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) or [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) listeners and use text editors which don't load the full file into memory for inspecting the response.